# Auto variable to store function pointer to std::max

Tags: c++, templates, auto, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to pass function `std::max` as template parameter to a templated function, but for some reasons compiler prints error that function type cannot be deduced. A simple example reproduces the same issue. It works with own `max2` function but doesn't work with STL `std::max`:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
T max2(const T& a, const T& b) { return std::max(a, b); }

int main() {
#if 1
  auto f = max2<float>;
#else
  // error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘max<float>’
  auto f = std::max<float>;
#endif
  float max_val = f(1.0f, 2.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that [there are several `std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) and the compiler doesn't know which one you want.

Comment: I personally prefer the style of template functions where you create a (non-template) class, and give it a template function call operator (perhaps more than one with different signatures), and then pass around an object of that class. Then you don't even have to specify the template parameter. You can just pass `max`, instead of `max<float>` or worse, the abominable static cast required when you have multiple free function overloads. The [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library does this for all of its functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As seen [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max), `std::max<float>` isn't a single, unambiguous function. At this point, it's an overload set and there are still two possibilities:

```
constexpr const float& max( const float& a, const float& b );
constexpr float max( std::initializer_list<float> ilist );
```

You have two main options:

1. Wrap it in a lambda:

   ```
    auto f = [](float a, float b) { return std::max(a, b); };
    // Note there's no by-reference behaviour in this lambda.
   ```
2. If you want something more reusable, you'll need to wrap it separately, e.g., as something that doesn't require shenanigans to pass around:

   ```
    struct max_fn {
        template<typename T>
        const T& operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {
            return std::max(a, b);
        }
    };
   ```

Obviously #2 comes with significant boilerplate, and that's ignoring other overloads and `constexpr`. In the future, it is expected that you will be able to do better. Today, you could emulate such a thing with a macro (most simply done by making the macro expand into a lambda). I've come across at least one `LIFT` macro that does this.

There's a third option that can be appealing because it's one line (an ugly line, but one line), and that's casting to the correct function pointer type. However, this isn't allowed except in a few special cases per [[namespace.std]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/requirements#namespace.std-6).