# transform_reduce with max_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, transform, reduce

I am trying to use transform_reduce to transform a set of numbers and then reduce it to the maximum of those elements.

```
auto lambda = [](uint64_t x) {
     return function(x);
 };

 counting_iterator<uint64_t> start(1);
 counting_iterator<uint64_t> finish(bound);


 auto max_val = *transform_reduce(start, finish, lambda, std::max_element(start, finish));
```

My logic is that it will change all the values from 1 to bound to function(1) to function(bound), then with those values, give me the largest, but I am having issues, can anyone help me get to want I want to achieve?

Comment: `but I am having issues` describe your issues.

Answer (score 2):

Signature of `std::transform_reduce` (which takes one range) is:

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOp, class UnaryOp>
T transform_reduce(InputIt first, InputIt last,
               T init, BinaryOp binop, UnaryOp unary_op);
```

So, in your case:

```
auto max_val =
    std::transform_reduce(start, finish,
                          lambda(*start),
                          [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return std::max(lhs, rhs); },
                          lambda);
```

if legal (but it is not), `[](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return std::max(lhs, rhs); }` could be replaced by `using lambda_t = decltype(lambda(*start)); static_cast<const lambda_t & (*)(const lambda_t&, const lambda_t&)>(&std::max<lambda_t>)`
as `std::max<T>` would be ambiguous (might be `max(const T&, const T&)` or `max(std::initializer_list<T>)`), so the additional cast.

But anyway, we are not allowed to take address of most `std` functions, including `std::max`.

Comment: Are you sure about the last paragraph? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Nikolai: I generally use coliru or godbold, but they don't support `std::transform_reduce` :( (even cppreference example)...

Comment: The substitution suggested in the last paragraph is not legal because std::max is still ambiguous even with the template argument specified. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625376/auto-variable-to-store-function-pointer-to-stdmax

Comment: @RyanCu: Clarified the fact that taking address of `std::max` is illegal, even when selecting right overload (and the way to select right overload).